# Extend chapter heading numbers into margin

Tags: koma-script

In my earlier question, I got a very helpful response on extending section headings in a KomaScript article document into the margins: [Extending section heading underline into margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493982/extending-section-heading-underline-into-margin)

The MWE answer was:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames,table,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,oneside,DIV=9]{scrartcl}

% Packages
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{xcolor} % showframe loads this
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% demo only
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}

% theme colours
\definecolor{MyThemeColour}{cmyk}{0.10,0.10,1.00,0} % personal yellow

\newlength{\mysecnumhang}
\setlength{\mysecnumhang}{30pt}
% KOMA and general setup
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{%
  \makebox[\mysecnumhang][l]{\thesection\autodot\enskip}%
}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionformat}{%
  \makebox[\mysecnumhang][l]{\thesubsection\autodot\enskip}%
}
\renewcommand*{\subsubsectionformat}{%
  \makebox[\mysecnumhang][l]{\thesubsubsection\autodot\enskip}%
}

\newbox\tmpseclinenobox
\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \sbox\tmpseclinenobox{#3}%
  \ifdim\wd\tmpseclinenobox>0pt\hspace{-\mysecnumhang}\fi
  \expandafter\headuline{#3#4}%
}

\newcommand\headuline{%
    \bgroup\markoverwith{\textcolor{MyThemeColour}{\rule[-0.75ex]{1pt}{1pt}}}\ULon% 2pt 2pt
    }

% recalc the text block after all the font loading
\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}

\begin{document}
\section*{Lipsum}
Some text.
\section{Lipsum}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

If I change the class to `scrbook` and add some `\chapter{}\s to it, I can't seem to replicate the effect with the chapter headings.

Would anyone feel able to update the MWE to deal with chapters?

Comment: @Andrew Swann provided the original answer I've used as the MWE above…

Comment: Adding an illustration of why the first answer isn't quite right…

Comment: And removed with the comment below explaining further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redefine `\chapterformat` in the same way:

```latex
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \makebox[\mysecnumhang][l]{\thechapter\autodot\enskip}%
}
```

and redefine `\chapterlinesformat`:

```latex
\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
  \sbox\tmpseclinenobox{#2}%
  \ifdim\wd\tmpseclinenobox>0pt\hspace{-\mysecnumhang}\fi
  \expandafter\headuline{#2#3}%
}
```

or

```latex
\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
  \Ifstr{#2}{}{}{\hspace{-\mysecnumhang}}%
  \expandafter\headuline{#2#3}%
}
```

Example:

```latex
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames,table,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,oneside,DIV=9]{scrbook}

% demo only
\usepackage{mwe}

% Packages
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{xcolor} % showframe loads this
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% theme colours
\definecolor{MyThemeColour}{cmyk}{0.10,0.10,1.00,0} % personal yellow

\newlength{\mysecnumhang}
\setlength{\mysecnumhang}{30pt}
% KOMA and general setup
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \makebox[\mysecnumhang][l]{\thechapter\autodot\enskip}%
}
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{%
  \makebox[\mysecnumhang][l]{\thesection\autodot\enskip}%
}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionformat}{%
  \makebox[\mysecnumhang][l]{\thesubsection\autodot\enskip}%
}
\renewcommand*{\subsubsectionformat}{%
  \makebox[\mysecnumhang][l]{\thesubsubsection\autodot\enskip}%
}

\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
  \Ifstr{#2}{}{}{\hspace{-\mysecnumhang}}%
  \expandafter\headuline{#2#3}%
}
\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \Ifstr{#3}{}{}{\hspace{-\mysecnumhang}}%
  \expandafter\headuline{#3#4}%
}

\newcommand\headuline{%
  \bgroup\markoverwith{\textcolor{MyThemeColour}{\rule[-0.75ex]{1pt}{1pt}}}\ULon% 2pt 2pt
}

% recalc the text block after all the font loading
\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}

\begin{document}
\addchap{Foo}
\addsec*{Lipsum}
Some text.
\section{Lipsum}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Additional remark: The solution is limited to one line headings because of the underline.

---

Regarding a comment below:

If you visualize the bounding box of the letters in the headings (using eg. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57860), the alignment of the heading texts will be  visible:

[image]

Code for the picture:

```latex
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames,table,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,oneside,DIV=9]{scrbook}

% demo only
\usepackage{mwe}

% Packages
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{xcolor} % showframe loads this
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

% theme colours
\definecolor{MyThemeColour}{cmyk}{0.10,0.10,1.00,0} % personal yellow

\newlength{\mysecnumhang}
\setlength{\mysecnumhang}{30pt}
% KOMA and general setup
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \makebox[\mysecnumhang][l]{\thechapter\autodot\enskip}%
}
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{%
  \makebox[\mysecnumhang][l]{\thesection\autodot\enskip}%
}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionformat}{%
  \makebox[\mysecnumhang][l]{\thesubsection\autodot\enskip}%
}
\renewcommand*{\subsubsectionformat}{%
  \makebox[\mysecnumhang][l]{\thesubsubsection\autodot\enskip}%
}

\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
  \Ifstr{#2}{}{}{\hspace{-\mysecnumhang}}%
  \expandafter\headuline{#2#3}%
}
\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \Ifstr{#3}{}{}{\hspace{-\mysecnumhang}}%
  \expandafter\headuline{#3#4}%
}

\newcommand\headuline{%
  \bgroup\markoverwith{\textcolor{MyThemeColour}{\rule[-0.75ex]{1pt}{1pt}}}\ULon% 2pt 2pt
}


% recalc the text block after all the font loading
\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}

% show bounding box for each letter (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57860)
\makeatletter
\def\showboxes#1{%
  \begingroup\color{red}\fboxrule=.1pt \fboxsep=-\fboxrule
  \@showboxes#1\@showboxes\@empty
  \endgroup}
\def\@showboxes#1#2{%
  \ifx#2\@showboxes
    \fbox{\color{gray}#1}\expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \setbox0=\hbox{#1\kern0pt#2}\setbox2=\hbox{#1#2}%
    \dimen0=\wd0 \advance\dimen0 -\wd2 % \dimen0 contains the kern between the two chars
    \fbox{\color{gray}#1}\kern-\dimen0
    \expandafter\@showboxes
  \fi#2}

\begin{document}
\chapter{\showboxes{Lipsum}}
\section{\showboxes{Lipsum}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't post an image in a comment — this is v close to working but doesn't quite align text correctly. I'll edit the original question to show what I mean.

Comment: The text is aligned. But if you the font is enlarged, the bounding boxes of the letters are enlarged too. See my updated answer.

Comment: Ah, ok that makes it clearer. Thank you!

Comment: Frustratingly, this solution doesn't work in my larger thesis document. It seems to break the `\tableofcontents` command somehow. It must be some other interaction with packages loaded for the thesis, I guess

Comment: I get the following error in my thesis file:

Comment: /Users/lyndon/repo/writing/input-thesis/thesis_jeremiah_32_as_economic_metaphor.tex:194: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\UL@stop ...alty \ifnum \lastkern =\thr@@ \egroup 
                                                  \egroup \ifdim \wd \UL@box...
l.194 \tableofcontents

Comment: Any thoughts? I'm puzzled by why the identical section formatting commands don't trigger it

Comment: Sorry, but I can not reproduce the issue if I add `\tableofcontents` to my code. Maybe you have to ask a new question including a MWE showing your issue. Do you load another package regarding ToC, eg. `tocloft`? Or there are other changes for the ToC in your code?

Comment: Yep in the MWE it works fine, and it must be an interacting package. I'll do the tedious (!) job of getting the thesis down to an MWE in due course and post a new question. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: OK, so the problem is if I have a bibliography file (I'm not even doing citations or generating the bibliography). Just the line, `\addbibresource{~/repo/workflow/zot-export.bib}` is enough to break the MWE

Comment: Sorry, but I can not reproduce the issue, if I load package `biblatex` and add `\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}` (I do not have your bib file) to the preamble. Even if I use `\nocite{*}` and `\printbibliography` with or without option `heading=totoc`, I do not get any error with my code.

Comment: Must be something in my `.bib` file then. I'll investigate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123367/discussion-between-lyndon-drake-and-esdd).